# Receiving SW=`"6999", "6422", "6444" and "6D00" in the simulating procedure with NetBeans , CREF and JCWDE?

Tags: netbeans, javacard

A simple 8 byte random number generator program is written in NetBeans for Java Card.

This is the program :

```
public class RandGen extends Applet {
    byte[] generatedArray;
    RandomData randData =   RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);

    private RandGen() {
        generatedArray = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)8, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new RandGen().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        byte[] byffer = arg0.getBuffer();
        byte[] generatedRandom = MyGenerator(arg0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, byffer, (short) 0,
                (short) generatedRandom.length);
        arg0.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) generatedRandom.length);
    }

    public byte[] MyGenerator(APDU apdu) {
        randData.generateData(generatedArray, (short) 0, (short) 8);
        return generatedArray;
    }

}
```

I clicked on the hammer button to build the project and after that the green triangle to run the project on the simulator as follow :

[image]

**Questions :**

When I follow the above process for a HelloWorld applet, in the section *3* (Of above image) my applet AID appears and in the section *4* the simulator returns SW=`9000` in response of the command. But for the above program, as you see, neither the applet AID appears, nor the SW=`9000`. Why?

For the HelloWorld applet, I right click on the *Default Device* and select *Console* and send APDU commands, and the card returns expected APDU responses. But for this applet, it returns `SW=6999` only. Why?

**Additional information :**

I receive some different Status Words when I tried to simulate this applet using *CREF* and *JCWDE* also :

This is contents of *MyScrip.script* file that I used in the below simulation :

```
powerup;
// Select the installer applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09 0xa0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0x08 0x01 0x7F;
0x80 0xB0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/Header.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x01 0x00 0x17 0x01 0x00 0x14 0xDE 0xCA 0xFF 0xED 0x01 0x02 0x04 0x00 0x01 0x0A 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/Directory.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x02 0x00 0x20 0x02 0x00 0x1F 0x00 0x14 0x00 0x1F 0x00 0x0F 0x00 0x1F 0x00 0x32 0x00 0x0E 0x00 0x51 0x00 0x0A 0x00 0x13 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x83 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x02 0x00 0x02 0x01 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/Import.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x04 0x00 0x20 0x04 0x00 0x1F 0x03 0x03 0x01 0x07 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x01 0x01 0x03 0x01 0x07 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x01 0x07 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x04 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x01 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/Applet.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x03 0x00 0x12 0x03 0x00 0x0F 0x01 0x0B 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x16 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/Class.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x06 0x00 0x11 0x06 0x00 0x0E 0x00 0x80 0x03 0x02 0x00 0x02 0x07 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x23 0x00 0x42 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/Method.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x07 0x00 0x20 0x07 0x00 0x51 0x00 0x02 0x10 0x18 0x8C 0x00 0x03 0x18 0x10 0x08 0x90 0x0B 0x87 0x00 0x18 0x05 0x8D 0x00 0x02 0x87 0x01 0x7A 0x02 0x30 0x8F 0x00 0x04 0x3D 0x8C 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x07 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x05 0x8B 0x00 0x06 0x7A 0x05 0x22 0x19 0x8B 0x00 0x07 0x2D 0x18 0x19 0x8B 0x00 0x08 0x2E 0x1B 0x03 0x1A 0x03 0x1B 0x92 0x8D 0x00 0x09 0x3B 0x19 0x03 0x1B 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x07 0x00 0x14 0x92 0x8B 0x00 0x0A 0x7A 0x04 0x20 0xAD 0x01 0xAD 0x00 0x03 0x10 0x08 0x8B 0x00 0x0B 0xAD 0x00 0x77 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/StaticField.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x08 0x00 0x0D 0x08 0x00 0x0A 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/ConstantPool.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x05 0x00 0x20 0x05 0x00 0x32 0x00 0x0C 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x06 0x81 0x0E 0x00 0x06 0x80 0x03 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x03 0x80 0x03 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x05 0x00 0x15 0x01 0x03 0x80 0x0A 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x06 0x80 0x10 0x02 0x03 0x80 0x0A 0x08 0x03 0x81 0x0E 0x01 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// randGen/javacard/RefLocation.cap
0x80 0xB2 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB4 0x09 0x00 0x16 0x09 0x00 0x13 0x00 0x05 0x0D 0x07 0x31 0x02 0x08 0x00 0x0A 0x05 0x0C 0x08 0x04 0x03 0x07 0x06 0x0A 0x08 0x0D 0x7F;
0x80 0xBC 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

0x80 0xBA 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

// Select the installer applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09 0xa0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0x08 0x01 0x7F;
// create RandGen applet
// select RandGen applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0xb 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0xd 0xb 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F;

powerdown;
```

**1- CREF is running :** (Returns SW=`9000` for load cap commands, but SW=`6D00` and SW=`6444` for last commands)

```
C:\Java\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do\bin>apdutool.bat C:\Users\AmirEbrahim\Documents\EclipseProjects\RandomGenerator\bin\randGen\javacard\MyScript.script
Java Card 2.2.2 APDU Tool, Version 1.3
Copyright 2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
Opening connection to localhost on port 9025.
Connected.
Received ATR = 0x3b 0xf0 0x11 0x00 0xff 0x01
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b0, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 01, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 01, P2: 00, Lc: 17, 01, 00, 14, de, ca, ff, ed, 01, 02, 04, 00, 01, 0a, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 01, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 02, 00, 1f, 00, 14, 00, 1f, 00, 0f, 00, 1f, 00, 32, 00, 0e, 00, 51, 00, 0a, 00, 13, 00, 00, 00, 83, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 03, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 02, 01, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 04, 00, 1f, 03, 03, 01, 07, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 01, 01, 03, 01, 07, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 01, 02, 00, 01, 07, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 02, 00, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 03, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 03, P2: 00, Lc: 12, 03, 00, 0f, 01, 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 00, 00, 16, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 03, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 06, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 06, P2: 00, Lc: 11, 06, 00, 0e, 00, 80, 03, 02, 00, 02, 07, 02, 00, 00, 00, 23, 00, 42, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 06, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 07, 00, 51, 00, 02, 10, 18, 8c, 00, 03, 18, 10, 08, 90, 0b, 87, 00, 18, 05, 8d, 00, 02, 87, 01, 7a, 02, 30, 8f, 00, 04, 3d, 8c, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 00, 05, 8b, 00, 06, 7a, 05, 22, 19, 8b, 00, 07, 2d, 18, 19, 8b, 00, 08, 2e, 1b, 03, 1a, 03, 1b, 92, 8d, 00, 09, 3b, 19, 03, 1b, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 14, 92, 8b, 00, 0a, 7a, 04, 20, ad, 01, ad, 00, 03, 10, 08, 8b, 00, 0b, ad, 00, 77, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 08, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 08, P2: 00, Lc: 0d, 08, 00, 0a, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 08, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 05, 00, 32, 00, 0c, 02, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 01, 06, 81, 0e, 00, 06, 80, 03, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 06, 00, 00, 01, 03, 80, 03, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 15, 01, 03, 80, 0a, 01, 03, 00, 00, 08, 06, 80, 10, 02, 03, 80, 0a, 08, 03, 81, 0e, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 09, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 09, P2: 00, Lc: 16, 09, 00, 13, 00, 05, 0d, 07, 31, 02, 08, 00, 0a, 05, 0c, 08, 04, 03, 07, 06, 0a, 08, 0d, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 09, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: ba, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 6d, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b8, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 0d, 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 00, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 44
```

**2- JCWDE is running :** (Returns SW=`6421` for load cap commands, and SW=`6d00` and SW=`6444` for the last commands)

```
C:\Java\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do\bin>apdutool.bat C:\Users\AmirEbrahim\Documents\EclipseProjects\RandomGenerator\bin\randGen\javacard\MyScript.script
Java Card 2.2.2 APDU Tool, Version 1.3
Copyright 2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
Opening connection to localhost on port 9025.
Connected.
Received ATR = 0x3b 0xf0 0x11 0x00 0xff 0x00
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b0, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 01, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 01, P2: 00, Lc: 17, 01, 00, 14, de, ca, ff, ed, 01, 02, 04, 00, 01, 0a, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 3a
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 01, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 02, 00, 1f, 00, 14, 00, 1f, 00, 0f, 00, 1f, 00, 32, 00, 0e, 00, 51, 00, 0a, 00, 13, 00, 00, 00, 83, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 03, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 02, 01, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 02, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 04, 00, 1f, 03, 03, 01, 07, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 01, 01, 03, 01, 07, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 01, 02, 00, 01, 07, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 02, 00, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 03, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 03, P2: 00, Lc: 12, 03, 00, 0f, 01, 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 00, 00, 16, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 03, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 06, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 06, P2: 00, Lc: 11, 06, 00, 0e, 00, 80, 03, 02, 00, 02, 07, 02, 00, 00, 00, 23, 00, 42, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 06, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 07, 00, 51, 00, 02, 10, 18, 8c, 00, 03, 18, 10, 08, 90, 0b, 87, 00, 18, 05, 8d, 00, 02, 87, 01, 7a, 02, 30, 8f, 00, 04, 3d, 8c, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 00, 05, 8b, 00, 06, 7a, 05, 22, 19, 8b, 00, 07, 2d, 18, 19, 8b, 00, 08, 2e, 1b, 03, 1a, 03, 1b, 92, 8d, 00, 09, 3b, 19, 03, 1b, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 14, 92, 8b, 00, 0a, 7a, 04, 20, ad, 01, ad, 00, 03, 10, 08, 8b, 00, 0b, ad, 00, 77, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 07, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 08, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 08, P2: 00, Lc: 0d, 08, 00, 0a, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 08, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 20, 05, 00, 32, 00, 0c, 02, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 01, 06, 81, 0e, 00, 06, 80, 03, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 06, 00, 00, 01, 03, 80, 03, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 15, 01, 03, 80, 0a, 01, 03, 00, 00, 08, 06, 80, 10, 02, 03, 80, 0a, 08, 03, 81, 0e, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 05, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b2, P1: 09, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: b4, P1: 09, P2: 00, Lc: 16, 09, 00, 13, 00, 05, 0d, 07, 31, 02, 08, 00, 0a, 05, 0c, 08, 04, 03, 07, 06, 0a, 08, 0d, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: bc, P1: 09, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 80, INS: ba, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 21
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 6d, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: b8, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 0d, 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 00, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 44

C:\Java\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do\bin>
```

What's wrong with this applet?

Note that any comment to make the applet more efficient will also appreciate.

**Edit/Update: Output of CREF and JCWDE are different with each other. and is different with NetBeans also. (I was wrong in the previous edition)**

Comment: One way to make your code more efficient is to remove the line: "byte[] generatedArray = new byte[8];" This line allocates an EEPROM byte array (and is not garbage collected) everytime your applet receives an APDU command. Take note that accessing an EEPROM is slower than accessing data in RAM (APDU buffer). In addition to this, there is a limit to writing in each specific area in EEPROM and when this limit is reached, the EEPROM area will wear down which may break your card (card may not be usable anymore). You can store the generated random directly in the APDU buffer instead.

Comment: @Chooch Thank you. I moved that line to the class body. Now, If I don't want to generate random directly in the APDU buffer, is it the efficient?

Comment: Yes this is more efficient. But if you dont need the generated number on your next session, you can still optimize it a little more by declaring generatedArray as a RAM buffer. You can do this by declaring your variable byte[] generatedArray. Then in your constructor, generatedArray = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)8, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

Comment: @Chooch Thank you. I edited the question again. Am I did it correct?

Comment: @Chooch Now Eclipse can't convert it to _cap_ file anymore! (While NetBeans can!)- Eclipse returns **error: randGen: empty package.**

Comment: I have no idea why. Sorry, i cannot help you any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's simulator limitation problem to support `ALG_SECURE_RANDOM`.

Please try `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` instead.

From [Class RandomData](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/RandomData.html):

**ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM**

```
Utility pseudo-random number generation algorithms. The random number sequence generated by this algorithm need not be the same even if seeded with the same seed data.

Even if a transaction is in progress, the update of the internal state shall not participate in the transaction.
```

**ALG_SECURE_RANDOM**

Cryptographically secure random number generation algorithms.

P.S.
Also, try recreating the project from scratch.

Comment: Thanks.I test `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` and now **CREF** and **JCWDE** work fine (i.e. those return an 8 byte random number in reception of any command after selection.) But I have the same previous problem with NetBeans yet (i.e. my applet AID doesn't appear in the simulator and I receive SW=`6999` when I send APDU SELECT command). Does that mean the NetBeans support neither _Pseudo_ nor _Secure_ random algorithms?

Comment: Moreover, as a sub question do you have any experience in POS (Point of Sales) devices application's development?

Comment: Exactly not. Because I tested your applet with Netbeans IDE without any problem. Please go to `services` tab and in `Java Card Runtimes` right click on the `Default Device` and clear the EEPROM. Also always use `clean and build` instead of `build`. Maybe something should be cleaned before trying again. Let me know the results...

Comment: And about the `POS`, I have a very very basic understanding of that.

Comment: As a bounty, let's say every time use `if (selectingApplet()) return;` at the very beginning of the `process` method in order to return the select applet apdu and make the process method not to process this apdu

Comment: I cleared the EEPROM and then build it using `clean and build` and after that I clicked on the green triangle. After a while I have the same output, with this two line in the end of **build.xml** (in below of Netbeans screen) : 
`Received ATR = 0x3b 0xf0 0x11 0x00 0xff 0x00` 
`CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 06, c7, 61, 81, 91, 04, 07, Le: 00, SW1: 69, SW2: 99`
I don't have my applet AID in the right section yet.
About the `selectingApplet()`, you are right.but this is just a test applet.

Comment: Can we [continue this discussion in chat?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73010/discussion-between-abraham-and-hbizhi).