# I can't create java card applet. APDU response message is 0x6444, and i don't know what to check

Tags: applet, javacard, apdu

```
CMD>// Applet Instantiation APDU Script
//
// Package:     cryptoPack
// Package AID: //aid/A000000062/03010C01
// Applet:      CryptoDES
// Applet AID:  //aid/A000000062/03010C0101
//
// Select the installer applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0x08 0x01 0x7F;
APDU|CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
// Create CryptoDES applet
0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0x0C 0x0A 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0x0C 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x7F;
APDU|CLA: 80, INS: b8, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 0c, 0a, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 0c, 01, 01, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 44
```

I tested this code from [Java Card DES generator applet output is different from online-tools output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148089/java-card-des-generator-applet-output-is-different-from-online-tools-output). And my test environment is eclipse and java card platform. 
I compiled CryptoDES.java as Java Card Project. And first, I operated cap-cryptoPack script. Next, create-cryptoPack.CryptoDES script.
But, as above console, Sample_Device returned 0x6444. I don't know problem. Please help me.

```
package cryptoPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.CryptoException;
import javacard.security.DESKey;
import javacard.security.KeyBuilder;
import javacardx.crypto.Cipher;

public class CryptoDES extends Applet {

    // Array for the encryption/decryption key
    private byte[] TheDES_Key = { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00 };

    // Defining required Keys
    DESKey MyDES1Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES, false);
    DESKey MyDES2Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_2KEY, false);
    DESKey MyDES3Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_3KEY, false);

    byte ConfiguredKeyLength;

    // Defining required cipher
    Cipher MyCipher;

    // Defining switch case variables for supported instructions = INS in APDU command
    final byte SetKey = (byte) 0xC0;
    final byte OneKeyDES = (byte) 0xC1;
    final byte TwoKeyDES = (byte) 0xC2;
    final byte ThreeKeyDES = (byte) 0xC3;

    // Defining switch case variables for cipher algorithms = P1 in APDU command
    final byte DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1 = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2 = (byte) 0x01;
    final byte DES_CBC_NOPAD = (byte) 0x02;
    final byte DES_CBC_PKCS5 = (byte) 0x03;
    final byte DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1 = (byte) 0x04;
    final byte DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2 = (byte) 0x05;
    final byte DES_ECB_NOPAD = (byte) 0x06;
    final byte DES_ECB_PKCS5 = (byte) 0x07;

    // Defining Proprietary Status Words
    final short KeyInNotSetGood = 0x6440;

    // A flag to be sure that the configured key has the same length that the
    // algorithm needs.

    private CryptoDES() {

    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new CryptoDES().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {

        // Assigning 0 to "ConfiguredKeyLength" to force the user to use ...
        // ... "SetKey" command, after applet selection.
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            ConfiguredKeyLength = 0;
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Checking the CLA field in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        // Checking the P1 and P2 fields in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] > 7 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] > 1) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
        }

        // Analyzing the command.
        try {

            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

            case SetKey:
                SetCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(apdu);
                break;

            case OneKeyDES:

                OneKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);

                break;

            case TwoKeyDES:
                TwoKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);
                break;

            case (byte) ThreeKeyDES:
                ThreeKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);
                break;

            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);

            }

        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
        }

    }

    public void SetCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Key must has a length of 8, 16 or 24 bytes
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 8 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 16
                || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 24) {
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, TheDES_Key,
                    (short) 0, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);

            ConfiguredKeyLength = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];

        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
        case DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_NOPAD:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_PKCS5:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_PKCS5, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_NOPAD:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_NOPAD, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_PKCS5:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_PKCS5, false);
            break;

        }

    }

    public void OneKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not
        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 8) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }
        MyDES1Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES1Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES1Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void TwoKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not

        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 16) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }
        MyDES2Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES2Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES2Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void ThreeKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not
        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 24) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }

        MyDES3Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES3Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES3Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void DoEncryptDecrypt(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        byte[] CipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 32,
                JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

        short datalen = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        if ((datalen % 8) != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        MyCipher.doFinal(buffer, (short) 0, datalen, CipheredData, (short) 0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(CipheredData, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
                datalen);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, datalen);
    }

}
```

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/q/29021170/3899583 seems to be related to your problem... Have a look at it, please.

Comment: Ah! I wrote this program and now I'm just understand how awful it is! I apologize you for this piece of "shirt"! ;) (Simplest weakness is the naming conventions that I didn't followed in my program.). Anyway, try to install it on real Javacard, the origin of problem is the simulator, I think.